# MYSQL left join include not existing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, group-by

I currently have created the following extremely simplified mysql table that mimics the current tables i have.

promotion table:

```
CREATE TABLE promotion (
  promotion Varchar NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (promotion)
);
```

| sale_id |
| --- |
| 10% |
| 20% |
| 30% |

and sale table:

```
CREATE TABLE sale (
  sale_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  promotion Varchar,
  date Date NOT NULL,
  amount int,
  PRIMARY KEY (sale_id)
);
```

| sale_id | promotion | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 2022-1-1 | 100 |
| 2 | 10% | 2022-1-1 | 100 |
| 3 | 10% | 2022-1-1 | 100 |
| 4 | 20% | 2022-1-1 | 100 |
| 5 | null | 2022-1-2 | 100 |
| 6 | 10% | 2022-1-2 | 100 |
| 7 | 30% | 2022-1-2 | 100 |
| 8 | 30% | 2022-1-2 | 100 |

where promotion_id is a foreign key to the promotion table. So the relationship is that every sale can have either no promotion (null) or a promotion (int id value of the promotion's primary key as a foreign key).

I'm trying to display the data group by month and then promotion, wherein every month has a bunch of grouped sale amount totals grouped by promotion.

So far I have this query:

```
select
    Month(date),
    ifnull(promotion,'No Promo'),
    sum(amount)
from sale
    left join promotion p on p.promotion = sale.promotion
group by Month(date), sale.promotion
```

and this gives me the following results:

| month | promotion | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 100 |
| 1 | 10% | 200 |
| 1 | 20% | 100 |
| 2 | null | 100 |
| 2 | 10% | 100 |
| 2 | 30% | 200 |

But what i want is:

| month | promotion | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 100 |
| 1 | 10% | 200 |
| 1 | 20% | 100 |
| 1 | 30% | 0 |
| 2 | null | 100 |
| 2 | 10% | 100 |
| 2 | 20% | 0 |
| 2 | 30% | 200 |

Doesnt doing a right join mean including every promotion from the list of promotions in the promotion table? regardless if there was a sale with that promotion in that month?
Can anyone give me a hint in the right direction of why my right join is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to change the constraint in promotion from Primary Key to Unique to allow a null value. We can then use a cross join to create all the lines and left join onto sale to retrieve the values of goods sold.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE promotion (
>   promotion Varchar(4) 
>   UNIQUE
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO promotion VALUES (null),('10%'),('20%'),('30%');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sale (
>   sale_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   promotion Varchar(4),
>   date_ Date NOT NULL,
>   amount int
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into sale (promotion, date_, amount) values
> (null,'2022-1-1',100),
> ('10%','2022-1-1',100),
> ('20%','2022-1-1',100),
> ('30%','2022-1-1',100),
> (null,'2022-1-2',100),
> ('10%','2022-1-2',110),
> ('20%','2022-1-2',120),
> ('30%','2022-1-2',130),
> (null,'2022-2-1',75),
> ('10%','2022-2-1',75),
> ('30%','2022-2-1',75),
> (null,'2022-2-2',75),
> ('10%','2022-2-2',75),
> ('30%','2022-2-2',75);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select
>     Month(date_) month_,
>     ifnull(p.promotion,'No Promo') Promotion,
>     sum(amount) Total
> from sale
>     left join promotion p on p.promotion = sale.promotion
> group by Month(date_), ifnull(p.promotion,'No Promo');
> ```
>
> ```
> month_ | Promotion | Total
> -----: | :-------- | ----:
>      1 | No Promo  |   200
>      1 | 10%       |   210
>      1 | 20%       |   220
>      1 | 30%       |   230
>      2 | No Promo  |   150
>      2 | 10%       |   150
>      2 | 30%       |   150
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   m,
>   ifnull(p.promotion,'No Promo') Promotion,
>   sum(amount) Total
> from (select distinct month(date_) m from sale) m
> cross join
> promotion p
> left join sale s on m.m = month(date_) and p.promotion = s.promotion
> group by m, ifnull(p.promotion,'No Promo')
> order by m, ifnull(p.promotion,'No Promo');;
> ```
>
> ```
>  m | Promotion | Total
> -: | :-------- | ----:
>  1 | 10%       |   210
>  1 | 20%       |   220
>  1 | 30%       |   230
>  1 | No Promo  |  null
>  2 | 10%       |   150
>  2 | 20%       |  null
>  2 | 30%       |   150
>  2 | No Promo  |  null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9c24fba76265ff8c91e3303cc32a41d)*

Comment: This worked flawlessly, so correct me if i'm wrong but my understanding is the key was to cross join, to get a table of sales x promotions, and then join that with another table to get the non null promotions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inverse the order of your tables in the join. (A right join would also work, but is not supported in all versions)

```
select
    Month(date),
    ifnull(promotion,'No Promo'),
    sum(amount)
from promotion p
    left join sale on p.promotion = sale.promotion
group by Month(date), ifnull(promotion,'No Promo');
```

Comment: this doesnt work, throws the error: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.promotion.promotion' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; 

I get where you are going though, we first fetch all the promotions then join them to the sales table, but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Using `group by Month(date), ifnull(promotion,'No Promo')`  should solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

I've slightly modified your query and your table definitions and its working fine in dbFiddle.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE promotion (
>   promotion Varchar(4) NOT NULL
>   PRIMARY KEY
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO promotion VALUES ('10%'),('20%'),('30%');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sale (
>   sale_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   promotion Varchar(4),
>   date_ Date NOT NULL,
>   amount int
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into sale (promotion, date_, amount) values
> (null,'2022-1-1',100),
> ('10%','2022-1-1',100),
> ('20%','2022-1-1',100),
> ('30%','2022-1-1',100),
> (null,'2022-1-2',100),
> ('10%','2022-1-2',110),
> ('20%','2022-1-2',120),
> ('30%','2022-1-2',130),
> (null,'2022-2-1',75),
> ('10%','2022-2-1',75),
> ('20%','2022-2-1',75),
> ('30%','2022-2-1',75),
> (null,'2022-2-2',75),
> ('10%','2022-2-2',75),
> ('20%','2022-2-2',75),
> ('30%','2022-2-2',75);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select
>     Month(date_) month_,
>     ifnull(p.promotion,'No Promo') Promotion,
>     sum(amount) Total
> from sale
>     left join promotion p on p.promotion = sale.promotion
> group by Month(date_), ifnull(p.promotion,'No Promo');
> ```
>
> ```
> month_ | Promotion | Total
> -----: | :-------- | ----:
>      1 | No Promo  |   200
>      1 | 10%       |   210
>      1 | 20%       |   220
>      1 | 30%       |   230
>      2 | No Promo  |   150
>      2 | 10%       |   150
>      2 | 20%       |   150
>      2 | 30%       |   150
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29f15e166530d0575effccef61819e41)*

Comment: This works but is not what im trying to do. If you remove these two inserts : ('20%','2022-2-1',75) and ('20%','2022-2-1',75). The result set will not include      2 | 10%       |  0, which is what im trying to do. You can see that here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a22afdc0c8ef6a038e0307d105a574bc